# Creating an iso image from a dual layer dvd

Tags: bash, virtualbox

I created an iso file using mkisofs "for linux OS: RH 7". Mounting the image shows the same folders of the original source from which the iso is generated. However when using this iso image to install on top of RH6 in a VM, Virtualbox created VM keeps complaining : fatal could not read from the boot medium, system halted

Is a dual layer dvd handled differently ?

Comment: No, but if there's no boot catalog then you can't boot from it.

Comment: What's a boot catalog, what is its extension ?